# What is the alsamixer of Pulse Audio?

Tags: pulseaudio

I just installed Pulse Audio over my ALSA installation. Is there a Pulse Audio mixer, something like `alsamixer`, that I can use for tasks such as changing the microphone gain?

Answer (score 10):

Remember that Alsa is not removed when installing Pulseaudio. Pulseaudio *uses* Alsa in quite some extent and you could say it's a layer on top of Alsa.

There's `pavucontrol` (on Debian/Ubuntu also the package name). It allows you to do a little bit more configuration on the Pulseaudio server and Pulseaudio-managed things like Bluetooth audio profile selection. Some regular volume actions are just passed to the Alsa layer and are the same as adjusting them using `alsamixer` or alike.

[image: Pavucontrol screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

Turns out `alsamixer` is still usable, just change the soundcard.

Comment: Depends on what you want. `alsamixer` didn't help me, because I couldn't adjust the 5.1 channels separately. you need `pavucontrol` for that, as gertvdijk pointed out in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you, too, don't like to use the mouse: On Ubuntu 18.10 I found `pamix` as an ncurses-based alternative to pavucontrol. Use F1-F5 to switch tabs, vi-like (or arrow key) movement, see man page.

Answer (score 1):

While `pavucontrol` is the goto, and probably the best one out there, it's important to mention that *all* X11 mixers are likely Pulse Mixer as it's by far the most popular sound daemon.

For example on XFCE, you can change the Microphone gain with the little notifier application,

[image: Xfce mixer notifier applet]